# Issue with checking server status

Tags: php

I have a simple script to check if a server is online or offline, however this script doesn't seem to work on the servers I want.

This is the script:

```
$value = mysql_result($result,$i,"servername");
$value2 = mysql_result($result,$i,"serveraddress");
$value3 = mysql_result($result,$i,"portnumber");
$value4 = mysql_result($result,$i,"description");
$id = mysql_result($result,$i,"id");

ob_start();

if (!$socket = @fsockopen($value2, $value3, $errno, $errstr, 1))
{
    echo "&nbsp;<font color='red'><CENTRE><strong>OFFLINE</strong></CENTRE></font>";
}
else 
{
    echo "&nbsp;<font color='green'><CENTRE><strong>ONLINE</strong></CENTRE></font>";  

    fclose($socket);
}
$status = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

The problem is if I say use a Google address and port 80 it will show Google's online, if I use an external IP address and a port like 7000 or so it won't show if the server is online, despite it being online. I'm not sure why this is, I'm thinking its possibly because no data is being sent through the port at the time showing it's closed.

Can someone shed some light on this please and maybe rectify the situation.

Comment: do you mean `<center>` ?

Comment: I've removed some of the code that didn't relate to the actual question :)

Comment: lol yer i do thanks, not really the issue at hand but any helps good help :)

Comment: yer the center tags, that's the dyslectic in me lol

Comment: I'm dyslexic too ;) I feel your pain.

Comment: perhaps the port is closed by your admin